# apt update : invalid signature

Tags: upgrade, package-management, 17.04

I just went through upgrading a bunch of machines to Zesty today.  Most of the machines went fine, one is being a PITA.  I had to go back a release and fix broken packages.  But now I'm on Zesty (I think).  But `sudo apt update` is croaking with

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've see a bunch of related questions here, but before you mark this as a duplicate:

1) I'm not getting BADSIG or NODATA or any other kind of hint.  Just "signatures were invalid".

2) I've tried moving/recreating /var/lib/apt/lists/ and it doesn't change anything.

3) I can't tell if that error message is actually stopping the search for upgraded packages, or if it's just something informational.

4) I have no idea why "precise" is in the mix at all.  that was 10+ releases ago

5) I'm sorry for asking too many questions on one post :)

Comment: Reposted from a comment by user696339: *I simply wanted to state I'm obtaining the same error and the methods described above by Chris to address the fix result in the same thing...17.04 (zesty) bug?*

Comment: FWIW, I "recovered" from this by booting the box from a USB stick as if I was going to do a new install.  You start the "new install" process, and then it will ask you if you want to try to keep the existing install.  You may lose your existing packages and mount points (I did), but at least it keeps your home directories around and does not muck with any other data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: The repository 'http//archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120194/e-the-repository-http-archive-canonical-com-precise-release-is-not-signed)