# GPG error: The following signatures were invalid: ########

Tags: 18.04, updates

I got this issue while running apt update command :

```
    Err:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease [55.7 kB]
Err:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease [55.7 kB]
Err:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release.gpg [198 B]
Ign:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done   
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 23E7166788B63E1E Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
E: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have run some commands to fix another issue after that I don't know which file has been deleted and this update issue occurred. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: You've tagged bionic (18.04) but your messages are from an EOL/ESM release (precise/12.04) which is off-topic here.  If you're using an ESM release you're supported by Canonical only though Ubuntu Advantage but off-topic here, if using an LTS release due to EOL status, you're off-topic - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) and [E: The repository 'http//archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed](https://askubuntu.com/q/1120194/)