# I messed up with sudo apt-get update and apt-get-repository? Now want to reset both to default

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, updates

I think I have messed up with both `sudo apt-get` update and `sudo apt-get-repository`. so initially I tried to update the version of R from 3.6 to higher. so I tried this image 1.

in order to update the R in I have followed these commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/' 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install r-base
```

but this did not work and thereafter whenever I was trying to update only one package get updated.

[image]

Although the further process did not go that well. but after that the problem has occurred. Now after that whenever I tried to do `sudo apt-get update` it just update only one package. but also gives some errors during update as well.

[image]

so I tried to figure out by looking at some solution and I did this

[image]

now I want to restore the `sudo apt-get update` command to its actual working so that it will update all the packages to their latest version. I tried to figure out the repository list from source.list and started adding one by one but again it didnot work.

[image]

what should I do to restore the working of apt-get update?

Comment: The problem is likely the old unsupported `saucy` repositiories rather than the bionic-cran35 repository that you tried to add

Comment: my current version is 18.04

Comment: okay so what should I do now?

Comment: i googled the same problem.. I thought i have nothing in my repository so in order to add I checked for the latest apt-get-repository and tried to add it image 3

Comment: i have followed these set of commands initially to update the version of R:

Comment: > sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/'
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install r-base

Comment: @user68186 I have updated the question.

Comment: Also see [the answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120194/e-the-repository-http-archive-canonical-com-precise-release-is-not-signed).

Comment: @Kulfy I'll try

Comment: @user68186 I'm using Ubuntu app in windows.

Comment: The command line method section at the [bottom of the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120194/e-the-repository-http-archive-canonical-com-precise-release-is-not-signed/1120198#1120198) should work!

Comment: yes.. finally it worked. thank you so much @Kulfy

Comment: thank you so much @user68186