# Unable to use sudo apt-get update: "NO_PUBKEY 26EB39123AAAAA96"

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

Every time I try to run `apt-get update`, I get the message below:

```
W: GPG error: http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 26EB39123AAAAA96
```

I'm quite new to Ubuntu, and Linux/Terminal in general, so despite as much as I've looked around and tried solutions, I can't seem to solve it.

I've tried `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 26EB39123AAAAA96` which results in:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.U6CXBaZaHQ/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 26EB39123AAAAA96
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
```

I also tried `sudo apt-key update`, which resulted in this:

```
Warning: 'apt-key update' is deprecated and should not be used anymore!
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 3
gpg:              unchanged: 3
```

I'm at an absolute loss here. I use this machine regularly, and can't update some of my packages, which is causing a couple of programs to not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can also provide any other necessary info.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you tell is the application package or the repository this public key is related to? Please edit your question with the new information.

Comment: I'm honestly not entirely sure, how would I find this?

Comment: The `sudo apt update` error should tell you which repository can't be accessed because of this key.

Comment: I see `W: GPG error: http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 26EB39123AAAAA96`, is that it? If that's the case, I'm at a loss, because I uninstalled OpenVPN

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1298042/edit) and add the above information in your question. This will help others understand your problem better.

Comment: This means the problem is with the repository website `as-repository.openvpn.net`. This is not a standard Ubuntu repository. It is possible they changed their private-public key pair recently.

Comment: Ah. Is there any way to just remove the entirety of OpenVPN then? I thought I already did, apparently I failed

Comment: Can you just remove the offending repo? I don't know how you added it, but it should be somewhere in /etc/apt, probably in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120194/e-the-repository-http-archive-canonical-com-precise-release-is-not-signed/1120198#1120198) for solutions to a similar problem.

Comment: Removing the OpenVPN repo worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

found that this works

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

Thanks to https://  [www.osmage.com/no-signature-ubuntu/](http://www.osmage.com/no-signature-ubuntu/)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the keys are still valid, so you should be able to get them imported with the following: `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys {key}`

Here is what I get for each of them:

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

From here, you can `sudo apt-get update` and everything should work.

Hope this helps

Comment: Just gave that a try, getting "gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data"

Comment: Perhaps a different key server would work. Try `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com` instead: `gpg —keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys {key}`

Comment: Still getting `gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data`. Bizarre.

Comment: Wow! It worked for me. Thank you