# How to fix this error when running sudo apt-get update?

Tags: 20.04, sudo

I'm getting the error below when I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Any idea how this can be fixed?

[image: check the highlighted error]

Comment: You have configured some repositories to look for `eoan` and some other for `focal`. If you are running Focal Fossa (20.04), you can delete all the entries in files referring to `eoan` in `/etc/apt/`

Comment: you have some references to Eoan Ermine (19.10) which is EOL since July this year: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: See the answer to this question: [E: The repository 'http//archive.canonical.com precise Release' is not signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120194/e-the-repository-http-archive-canonical-com-precise-release-is-not-signed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and open apt source list:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(You can use other editor, but you have to open with sudo)

Search for

> deb http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release

And remove that line. It's from an older version of ubuntu which is not supported in 20.04 (focal).

Then you must save and do

```
sudo apt update
```

and shouldn't be any more error.